# Adding Functionality To An Object Without Changing The Interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

I have an object presented as a reference/pointer to an interface.  I would like to call a method on the concrete object if that method is present, without changing the interface, breaking encapsulation, or writing any horrible hacks.  How can it be done?

Here's an example.

I have an interface:

```
class IChatty
{
public:
    virtual ~IChatty() {};
    virtual std::string Speak() const = 0;
};
```

And multiple concrete implementation of this interface:

```
class SimpleChatty : public IChatty
{
public:
    ~SimpleChatty() {};

    virtual std::string Speak() const override
    {
        return "hello";
    }
};

class SuperChatty : public IChatty
{
public:
    void AddToDictionary(const std::string& word)
    {
        words_.insert(word);
    }
    virtual std::string Speak() const override
    {
        std::string ret;
        for(auto w = words_.begin(); w != words_.end(); ++w )
        {
            ret += *w;
            ret += " ";
        }
        return ret;
    }
private:
    std::set<std::string> words_;
};
```

The `SuperChatty::AddToDictionary` method is not present in the abstract `IChatty` interface, although it could be included in another, new interface.

In the real world, these objects are constructed through factories, themselves concrete instantiations of an abstract interface.  However for our purposes that's orthogonal to the problem at hand:

```
int main()
{
    IChatty* chatty = new SuperChatty;
    chatty->AddToDictionary("foo");
    std::cout << chatty->Speak() << std::endl;
}
```

Since `AddToDictionary` isn't part of the `IChatty` interface (and *can't* be part of it), I can's call it.

How can I call `AddToDictionary` on the `chatty` pointer without breaking encapsulation, writing some horrible hack, or taking any other design shortcuts?

NOTE:  In the real world, the dictionary is part of the `SuperChatty` object itself, and cannot be separate from it.

NOTE2:  I do not want to downcast to the concrete type.

Comment: dynamic_cast is your friend.

Comment: @snipes83 Er... no it's not.

Comment: @snipes83:  If you mean something like, `dynamic_cast<SuperChatty*>(chatty)`, then `dynamic_cast` is a hack.  Relying on the ability to cast a pointer to an abstract interface to a pointer to a concrete type defeats the purpose of using the abstract interface in the first place.

Comment: Usually we should design a well abstraction to avoid run-time casts, otherwise, `dynamic_cast` is the final escape.

Comment: @MM.:  OK, given the general parameters of what I'm trying to achieve in code above, how would you have designed the abstraction?

Comment: @JohnDibling: not to `SuperChatty`, `dynamic_cast<IDictionary*>(chatty)`, where `IDictionary` is a new interface containing `AddToDictionary` and which is a base of `SuperChatty`. Attempting a dynamic cast *to an interface* isn't a hack, it's the mechanism that C++ provides for testing whether an object implements the interface.

Comment: Run-time type checks are a code smell in c++, and your best bet is to avoid this entirely. Instead, write a different interface with a default nop implementation which your concrete class overrides. Avoid dynamic_cast and RTTI unless you're willing to accept the flavor of a kluge.

Comment: I can't change the interface.

Comment: @JohnDibling What about using a variant of the command pattern and using an `ISpeaker` interface which requires `Speak()`. Then `SuperSpeaker` (which implements `ISpeaker`) can take a dictionary object in constructor, while `SimpleSpeaker` does not. The dictionary then has methods for adding words etc. The `IChatty` instances then uses their `ISpeaker` objects to call `Speak()`..

Comment: @snipes83:  I think I see what you're saying, and I agree that in general that's much better.  The only problem I have with it is the fact that in the RW the dictionary is part of the object itself, and can't be moved out of it.

Comment: An aside, inheritance from interfaces should normally be `virtual`. Then should you need to later, you can have interfaces derived from other interfaces, and class hierarchies interacting with the interface hierarchy, without creating ambiguous bases.

Answer (score 6):

Have dictionary be an object which can be updated and referenced by `SuperChatty`:

```
class Dictionary {
public:
    void add(const std::string& word);
    const std::set<std::string>>& words() const;
    //..
};

class SuperChatty : public IChatty
{
public:
    SuperChatty(Dictionary& dictionary) :
    dictionary(dictionary) {
    }

    virtual std::string Speak() const override
    {
        auto words = dictionary.words();
        ostringstream oss;
        copy(words.begin(), words.end(),
             ostream_iterator<string>(oss, " "));
        return oss.str();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{   
    Dictionary dictionary;
    IChatty* chatty = new SuperChatty(dictionary);
    dictionary.add("foo");
    std::cout << chatty->Speak() << std::endl;
}
```

*edit*

Okay, the question changed.

If you're doing this properly, you need to isolate yourself from the bad underlying system:

```
struct Dictionary {
    virtual ~Dictionary () {}
    virtual void add(const std::string& word) = 0;
};

struct Instrumenter {
    virtual ~Instrumenter () {}
    virtual void addDictionary(Dictionary& dictionary) = 0;
};

struct Chatter {
    virtual ~Chatter() {}
    virtual string speak() const = 0;
    virtual void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) = 0;
};
```

These are implemented as:

```
class BasicChatter : public Chatter {
    virtual string speak() const {
        return chatty.Speak();
    }
    virtual void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) {
        // do nothing
    }
private:
    SimpleChatty chatty;
};

class SuperChatter : public Chatter {
    SuperChatter () : dictionary(chatty);

    virtual void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) {
        instrumenter.addDictionary(dictionary);
    }

    virtual string speak() const {
        return chatty.Speak();
    }
private:
    SuperChatty chatty;
    DictionaryImpl dictionary;
};
```

Comment: good suggestion, but Dictionary should have it's own interface

Comment: I love interfaces, but why the `should`?

Comment: @PeterWood: for example so that you can provide a stub `IDictionary` implementation when you're unit-testing `SuperChatty`. The general rule of thumb is that since `SuperChatty` has a dependency, the dependency should be on an interface and not on a concrete class.

Comment: And how do you get to the dictionary when you are deep inside some other function that doesn't know whether this object has a dictionary or not? [As explained by the original poster in a comment on my suggestion].

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't know the system, obviously, but who/what can update a dictionary is specific to the domain. Maybe it's global, maybe it's per `Chatty` implementation. If it's per `Chatty`, then, for OP's original implementation, the application should store a list of `SuperChatty`s which can have their dictionaries' updated.

Comment: What you suggested is called dependency injection. As Steve Jessop mentioned, it is to simplify unit testing by providing a stub or mock class

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion as well.  I can't use it however, because the doctionary object is part of the `SuperChatty` object itself, and can't be separated from it.  I realize that I didn't make this clear initially, so I've edited the original post.

Comment: @JohnDibling I would keep a separate list then of `SuperChatty` references, which can have their dictionaries updated.

Comment: @JohnDibling: "*and can't be separated from it*" Why not? It seems to me that you're trapped in bad design. You don't seem to want inheritance at all; you want a component-based design, where each object has different optional components which you can query.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Because the dictionary is an essential part of the actual implementation.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Indeed the code in the question doesn't really use "inheritance" as such, so if the questioner doesn't want it that's OK, because he doesn't have it. It so happens that in C++ there's no special mechanism for interfaces, they're just base classes. So the use of interfaces is sometimes mistaken for inheritance ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Right, the code I've provided doesn't really *use* interfaces. However the real use case does.  Perhaps I've left out a bit too much detail in the search for brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Make it derive from another interface and simply check, whether you can cast the object to that interface or not.

```
class IDictionary
{
public:
    virtual ~IDictionary() {};
    virtual void AddToDictionary(const std::string& word) = 0;
};

class SuperChatty : public IChatty, public IDictionary
{
     ... as before ...
};

int main()
{
    IChatty* chatty = new SuperChatty;

    IDictionary *dict = dynamic_cast<IDictionary*>(chatty);
    if (dict) dict->AddToDictionary("foo");
    std::cout << chatty->Speak() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "...simply check whether you can cast..."  As in `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Yup. Compare with nullptr.

Comment: Hmm, this answer only has one upvote (mine), but my comment laying out the same idea has two. Maybe the crowd wants more detail in answers :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Yes, indeed.  In fact, this is probably the way I will go, but without additional details that will be helpful to myself and future readers, I can't upvote or accept this answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for providing the example, I planned to add it later.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're trowing away information that you need.

So the main solution is to not throw away information, but there's not enough code presented to flesh out the details of that.

Secondly, a tehcnical kludge solution is to just downcast, using `dynamic_cast`:

```
IChatty* newThingy();

int main()
{
    IChatty* chatty = newThingy();
    if( SuperChatty* p_super_chatty = dynamic_cast<SuperChatty*>( chatty ) )
    {
        p_super_chatty->AddToDictionary("foo");
    }
    std::cout << chatty->Speak() << std::endl;
}
```

You can downcast safely because the know static type `IChatty` is polymorphic.

Comment: Although this is what I have actually done up to now, it is a horrible hack.  I came to SO with this question because I'm trying to get rid of this horrible hack.

Comment: You're right. I should have clarified that downcasting to the concrete type is a horrible hack.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, there's no reason to not create the object as this:

```
SuperChatty* chatty = new SuperChatty;

chatty->AddToDictionary("foo");
```

You can still pass `chatty` in the above segment as `IChatty` pointer or reference, e.g.

```
void Talk(IChatty *ch)
{
   ch->Speak();
}
```

[Likewise for storing the `chatty` in a `vector<IChatty*>` or something like that].

My point here is that if you are going to use the "new" interface functions, then you probably also want to create the class that has the new interface.

Adding code to "try to cast it", etc, gets very messy very quickly, and is error prone.

Comment: This is a contrived, oversimplified example.  As I mentioned, in the real world these objects are constructed via factories.  The analogue for `AddToDictonary` is not called until long, long after the object has been fully constructed.  At that point, all I have is a reference-to the Interface.

Comment: @JohnDibling How do you know you want to add words to a dictionary? Are you keeping track of that possibility somewhere? Make your `Chatty` classes advertise their capabilities to some higher level controls, e.g. `Chatty::enumerateCapabilities`.

Comment: @PeterWood: that would seem to be another "change `IChatty`" suggestion. These problems with a constraint of backward-compatibility to a published interface are interesting, because they teach us that C++ has tools to allow you to implement multiple small, focussed, independent interfaces rather than one giant catch-all. Writing code to test capabilities is just re-inventing `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @PeterWood:  The real world answer to your question is complex, but I think I can sum it up thusly:  Through other horrible hacks.  Those are a story for another day.